# javascript validations in jsp page

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp, struts2

I can't apply javascript validations on my jsp page which is result of a mapped action (I am using Struts 2).

Here's my add customer form .

### addCustomer.jsp

```
<% 
try{
if(session.getAttribute("user").toString().equals(""))
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.errorMessage{color:red;}
</style>



<script>  
function validateform(){  
var CustomerCode=document.myform.CustomerCode.value;  
var CustomerName=document.myform.CustomerName.value;  
var CustomerAddr1=document.myform.CustomerAddr1.value;  
var CustomerPinCode=document.myform.CustomerPinCode.value; 
var Email=document.myform.Email.value;  
var ContactNo=document.myform.ContactNo.value; 
var PrimaryCont_Person=document.myform.PrimaryCont_Person.value;  
var CreatedBy=document.myform.CreatedBy.value; 


if (CustomerCode==null || CustomerCode==""){  
  alert("Customer Code can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}


if (CustomerName==null || CustomerName==""){
      alert("Customer Name can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
if (CustomerAddr1==null ||CustomerAddr1==""){
      alert("Customer Address can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
if (CustomerPinCode==null || CustomerPinCode==""){
      alert("Pin Code can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}

if (isNaN(CustomerPinCode)){  
  alert("Enter Numeric value  for customer pin code");  
  return false;  
}
if (CustomerPinCode.length!=6){  
      alert("Enter valid 6 digit pin code");  
      return false;  
    }
var x=document.myform.Email.value;  
var atposition=x.indexOf("@");  
var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");  
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
  alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:"+atposition+"\n dotposition:"+dotposition);  
  return false;  
  }  

if (Email==null || Email==""){
      alert("Email can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}


if (isNaN(ContactNo)){  
      alert("Enter Numeric value only for contact Number");  
      return false;  
    }

if (PrimaryCont_Person==null || PrimaryCont_Person==""){
      alert("Primary Contact Person can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
else if (CreatedBy==null || CreatedBy==""){
      alert("Create-by can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}


}  
</script> 

</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">

<%@page import="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.RequestAware"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<jsp:include page="homePage.jsp"></jsp:include>

<br>
<br>
<center>
<s:form name="myform"  onsubmit="return validateform()" action="addCustomer">

<center>

            <table border="1" width="70%" cellpadding="15">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="20">Enter Information Here </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerCode" label="Customer Code"  ></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName" label="Customer Name"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerAddr1" label="Customer Address 1"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerAddr2" label="Customer Address 2"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield label="PinCode" type="text" name="CustomerPinCode" > <span id="CustomerPinCode"></span></s:textfield></tr>
<tr ><s:textfield type="email" name="Email" label="Email"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield label="Contact Number" type="text" name="ContactNo" ></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield label="Primary Contact Person" type="text" name="PrimaryCont_Person" ></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:select label="Status" 
        list="#{'N':'New', 'M':'Modified', 'D':'Delete'}" 
        name="RecordStatus" 
        value="1" /></tr>
<tr><s:select label="SActive/Inactive Flag" 
        list="#{'A':'Active', 'I':'Inactive'}" 
        name="Flag" 
        value="1" /></tr>
        <tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CreatedBy" value= "%{#session.user}" readonly="true" label="Created By"></s:textfield></tr>
<s:hidden name="Status" value="New" ></s:hidden>

<s:submit></s:submit>
<s:reset></s:reset>

 </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
</s:form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

### edit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.RequestAware"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*;" %>

<% 
try{
if(session.getAttribute("user").toString().equals(""))
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
%>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


<script>  
function validateform(){  
var CustomerCode=document.myform.CustomerCode.value;  
var CustomerName=document.myform.CustomerName.value;  
var CustomerAddr1=document.myform.CustomerAddr1.value;  
var CustomerPinCode=document.myform.CustomerPinCode.value; 
var Email=document.myform.Email.value;  
var ContactNo=document.myform.ContactNo.value; 
var PrimaryCont_Person=document.myform.PrimaryCont_Person.value;  
var CreatedBy=document.myform.CreatedBy.value; 


if (CustomerCode==null || CustomerCode==""){  
  alert("Customer Code can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}


if (CustomerName==null || CustomerName==""){
      alert("Customer Name can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
if (CustomerAddr1==null ||CustomerAddr1==""){
      alert("Customer Address can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
if (CustomerPinCode==null || CustomerPinCode==""){
      alert("Pin Code can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}

if (isNaN(CustomerPinCode)){  
  alert("Enter Numeric value  for customer pin code");  
  return false;  
}
if (CustomerPinCode.length!=6){  
      alert("Enter valid 6 digit pin code");  
      return false;  
    }
var x=document.myform.Email.value;  
var atposition=x.indexOf("@");  
var dotposition=x.lastIndexOf(".");  
if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=x.length){  
  alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:"+atposition+"\n dotposition:"+dotposition);  
  return false;  
  }  

if (Email==null || Email==""){
      alert("Email can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}


if (isNaN(ContactNo)){  
      alert("Enter Numeric value only for contact Number");  
      return false;  
    }

if (PrimaryCont_Person==null || PrimaryCont_Person==""){
      alert("Primary Contact Person can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}
else if (CreatedBy==null || CreatedBy==""){
      alert("Create-by can't be blank");  
      return false; 
}


}  
</script> 

</head>

<body bgcolor="lightblue">

<jsp:include page="homePage.jsp"></jsp:include>
<br>
<br>
<s:form name="myform"  onsubmit="return validateform()" action="modifyCustomer" >
 <center>
            <table id="customers" border="1" width="70%" cellpadding="10">
                <thead>
                   <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Enter Information Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
  <tr>  



  <s:if test="%{#session.customer.RecordStatus=='N'}">
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerCode" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerCode}" label ="Customer Code" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
</s:if>
<s:else >
    <tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerCode" readonly="true" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerCode}" label ="Customer Code" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
</s:else>

<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerName" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerName}" label ="Customer Name" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textarea type="text" name="CustomerAddr1" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerAddr1}" label ="Customer Address1" cssClass="bord"></s:textarea></tr>
<tr><s:textarea type="text" name="CustomerAddr2" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerAddr2}" label ="Customer Address 2" cssClass="bord"></s:textarea></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="CustomerPinCode" value="%{#session.customer.CustomerPinCode}" label ="Customer Pin Code" cssClass="bord"><span id="CustomerPinCode"></span></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="email" value="%{#session.customer.Email}" label ="Email" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="ContactNo" value="%{#session.customer.ContactNo}" label ="Contact Number" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="PrimaryCont_Person" value="%{#session.customer.PrimaryCont_Person}" label ="Primary Contact Person" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="RecordStatus" value="%{#session.customer.RecordStatus}" label ="Record Status" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>
<tr><s:textfield type="text" name="Flag" value="%{#session.customer.Flag}" label =" Active/Inactive Flag" cssClass="bord"></s:textfield></tr>

<s:if test="%{#session.customer.RecordStatus=='N'}">

</s:if>
<s:else >
<tr><s:hidden type="text" name="CreateDate" value="%{#session.customer.CreateDate}" ></s:hidden></tr>
<tr><s:hidden type="text" name="CreatedBy" value="%{#session.customer.CreatedBy}" ></s:hidden></tr>
<tr><s:hidden type="text" name="AuthorizedBy" value="%{#session.customer.AuthorizedBy}" ></s:hidden></tr>
<tr><s:hidden type="text" name="AuthorizedDate" value="%{#session.customer.AuthorizedDate}" ></s:hidden></tr>
</s:else>

<s:hidden name="Cust_ID" value="%{#session.customer.Cust_ID}"></s:hidden>
<s:hidden name="ModifiedBy" value="%{#session.customer.ModifiedBy}"></s:hidden>
<s:hidden name="Status" value="Modify" ></s:hidden>
<s:submit ></s:submit>
<tr>


<s:reset></s:reset>
</tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
</center>
</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

### struts.xml

```
<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<action name="addCustomer" class="webComp.maker.makerAction" method="execute">
            <result name="input">/addCustomer.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
</action>


<action name="Edit" class="webComp.maker.editAction" method="edit">

            <result name="success">/edit.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/index.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="modifyCustomer" class="webComp.maker.makerAction" method="modify">
            <result name="input">/edit.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/index.jsp</result>
</action>

</struts>
</package>
```

The same javascript validation is working on another jsp page. There are two similar forms, one for adding records and the other is to edit those records and submit them.

The validations are properly working on `addcustomer.jsp` but not on `edit.jsp`. Basically i need help with "client side validations". that is the primary concern for now !

Comment: What happened when you pressed submit button?

Comment: Unrelated, but holy smokes :( The JS validation will validate a single input at a time--painful if multiple errors. Pulling in `RequestAware` into a JSP makes zero sense; it's an interface that S2 checks on *actions*, not the servlets JSPs are compiled into. Not indenting anything makes everything illegible. You're checking the session in the JSP instead of in an interceptor or even a plain old filter; that's the wrong place for that behavior. Phone numbers aren't numbers, they're strings. Use CSS instead of inline styles. Etc.

Comment: i am using JS for client side validations ! need help with  " Client Side Validation ".